# How to redirect after successful login? [PHP]

Tags: php, authentication

I've created a login system. The registration page works like a charm. But there's some problem with the login page. When I try to login, it logs me in, but it stays on the same login page. I mean there is no visible change in the login page even after logging in. I want it to redirect after a successful login, I've tried headers but for some strange reason it didnt work.

My code (PHP in the page):

```
<?php  //Start the Session
session_start();
 require('connect.php');
//3. If the form is submitted or not.
//3.1 If the form is submitted
if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
//3.1.1 Assigning posted values to variables.
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
//3.1.2 Checking the values are existing in the database or not
$query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
//3.1.2 If the posted values are equal to the database values, then session will be created for the user.
if ($count == 1){
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
header("location:redirectafterlogin.php"); //header to redirect, but doesnt work
}else{
//3.1.3 If the login credentials doesn't match, he will be shown with an error message.
echo "Invalid Login Credentials.";
}
}

?>
```

HTML in the page:

```
<title> Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="usr_style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<!-- Form for logging in the users -->

<div class="register-form">

<p>Please login to continue</p>

<h1>Login</h1>
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
    <p><label>User Name : </label>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username" required placeholder="username" /></p>

     <p><label>Password&nbsp;&nbsp; : </label>
     <input id="password" type="password" name="password" required placeholder="password" /></p>

    <a class="btn" href="register.php">Register</a>
    <input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Redirectafterlogin.php code (Its basically a guestbook):

```
<body>
<div class="main">
<br>


        <div id="title"><h2>Post</h2></div>
        <br>
    <div id="f">
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="addpost.php">

    <table id="g">

        <td>Post</td>
        <td><textarea name="comment" placeholder="Please type your post here...." rows=10 cols=50 id="comment"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input id="btn" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Post" /> <input id="btn" type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    </form>

</div>
<hr>



<?php

$host=""; // Host name
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name=""; // Database name
$tbl_name=""; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server ");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 50";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>


<div id="post_info">
<br>


<div id="author">
Name:
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($rows['name']); ?> 
</div>

<div id="time">
Time: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($rows['datetime']); ?>
</div>

<br>

<div id="post">
<pre><?php echo htmlspecialchars($rows['comment']); ?></pre>
</div>

</div>
<br>

<?php
}
mysql_close(); //close database
?>
```

Error:

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /customers/7/e/5/sattapesatta.com/httpd.www/login.php:5) in /customers/7/e/5/sattapesatta.com/httpd.www/login.php on line 6 Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /customers/7/e/5/sattapesatta.com/httpd.www/login.php:5) in /customers/7/e/5/sattapesatta.com/httpd.www/login.php on line 6 1 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /customers/7/e/5/sattapesatta.com/httpd.www/login.php:5) in /customers/7/e/5/sattapesatta.com/httpd.www/login.php on line 20

Comment: Try `header("Location: http://www.yoursite.com/redirectafterlogin.php");` using a full `http` call.

Comment: Umm..?! Did you read the question? I did use headers, but for some strange reason they aren't working. Any other ways that I can redirect? Or am I putting the header in the wrong place?

Comment: Ummm.... Yeah, I read the question. Is that your full code, or is there more on the same page that we're not made aware of? You say your login is successful.

Comment: I think I placed the header at the wrong place. What do you think?

Comment: Do `var_dump($count);` or `echo $count;` right after `$count = mysql_num_rows($result);` see what's passing through. I'm guessing your login does not work, as you think it does. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to your script to check for issues

Comment: I have the error reporting already in place. And I'm sure that it is logging me in. I have a "members only page" I'm able to access it without any problem. But when I remove the cookie, i cant access the page. So i'm pretty sure that its logging me in. Anyway, I'll try it.

Comment: You haven't answered my other question from above *"is there more on the same page that we're not made aware of?"* "More" being "code".

Comment: It is logging me in. I echoed the count and it says "1"

Comment: There is a bit of html:

Comment: That's not what my question is about. Do you have a form inside the same page, html etc.? Plus, the error could also lie inside `redirectafterlogin.php` - So again, show us your full code.

Comment: Just give me a second. Posting the full code.

Comment: It's important to know if your HTML is above your PHP. Meaning, is HTML first and you have your PHP after?

Comment: Edited the OP. And no, PHP is on the top and the html is below it.

Comment: Another thing. You have `redirectafterlogin.php` and you capitalized it in your edit as being `Redirectafterlogin.php` - If your file is capitalized, then that's the problem. You would need to do `header("location:Redirectafterlogin.php");` Plus, why are you using `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;`? You're not using sessions in your next page.

Comment: No its not capitalized. The file's name is "redirectafterlogin.php" And if i'm typing the file name wrong, it should still redirect and give me a 404 error right?

Comment: And you're not getting any errors using `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); session_start(); // rest of your code`?

Comment: I dont use sessions in the next page, but the page after that. Since its a guestbook, the post entered in the redirectafterlogin.php is processed at addpost.php And i want only logged in users to post. So i use sessions in addpost.php

Comment: No, i dont get any errors

Comment: Ok, last few efforts. Try replacing `if ($count == 1){` with `if ($count >0){` and use your present header. If that doesn't work, change it back to `if ($count == 1){` then replace your `header...` with `echo "<meta http-equiv=Refresh content=1;url=redirectafterlogin.php>";` - If that doesn't work, it will mean your login failed. There are no other possible scenarios.

Comment: just got an error. updating the OP

Comment: Fred -ii- I updated the OP with the error. please take a look.

Comment: I had a feeling a cookie was at fault. That counts as output before headers. I suggest you use this format then. `<?php session_start();?>` then reopen PHP tags `<?php // cookie stuff, and rest of your code ?>` that should work. I asked you earlier about errors but you said no, why are you getting them now?

Comment: Still the Same error. I dont know. Earlier i was checking with an account that I inserted into the table using SQL queries. Now i tried with an account i registered using the registration page. :/

Comment: Ok well then, use `echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL="redirectafterlogin.php">';` in place of your header. I don't know what else to say that will be of any further help than I already have. You may even have a byte order mark.

Answer (score 5):

When you want to do a redirection with the function header, you have to write it properly for it to work.

```
header('Location: ...');
```

If you don't use the capital letter and the space after the colon, it will not work. Please read the manual on [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

(Edit)
I also saw in the comments to try to add the complete path, this is not necessary to make it work.

Comment: *"I also saw in the comments to try to add the complete path, this is not necessary to make it work."* Same thing goes for the uppercase `L`. What is not valid is `header(' Location: ...');` or `header(' location: ...');` with a space before `Location` or `location`. It's best to question first, then answer.

Comment: Not necessary that the location should have L as capital letter nor the space needed after the colon, I am using latest PHP version. Not sure about the older PHP version.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    header("Location: redirectafterlogin.php");
    exit;
```

Also from the PHP docs

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 1):

**The Most easy way:**

1. Put this before any html in your page (not even a single space should be before this code)`<? php ob_start(); ?>`
2. Use this -It's case sensitive-`<?php header("Location: youraddress.html");?>`
3. Close it when you finish    `<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>`

Answer (score -1):

Remove white spaces and newlines before header:

```
session_start();
 require('connect.php');
```

This should be:

```
session_start();
require('connect.php'); // whitespace removed
```

And your:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Should be just:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: *"Should be just:"* What am I missing here? They're both the same. Plus, `// whitespace removed` white space is for "above" that, not below `session_start();`

Comment: I just removed the spaces. Perhaps you are getting error "headers already sent". There should be no output before headers like whitespaces or next lines.

Comment: I tried removing the whitespaces, but still the same.

Comment: I dont get any errors. The page doesn't change. It almost looks like it reloaded.

Comment: You can check if headers are already sent, replace the redirect with :  `if (headers_sent()) { die("Redirect failed."); }`